# Upload file to FTP using PowerShell but File name dynamic

Tags: powershell

I have multiple files that needs to be sent to an FTP site.
These files are always .CSV but the file name keeps changing.

I have a PowerShell script that can send the files across successfully. But the code has the file name hard coded. I can't seem to find a way to pick the file name dynamically and write it to the FTP site with the dynamic file name. (hope that made sense)

Can someone please help?

Many thanks

Comment: Show us what kind of script you have got this far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there another attribute that you can use?  For example in my case I often have to choose the newest file in the directory.  I've done something similar using the LastWriteTime attribute.

```
$lastWrittenCSV = Get-ChildItem -Path C:\csvFiles\ -Filter *.csv | Sort-Object -Descending LastWriteTime | Select-Object -First 1
```

Then you can run your script against `$lastWrittenCSV.FullName` (the fully path) and upload it as `$lastWrittenCSV.Name` (just the name of the file).

You could even us some sort of flag file to keep track of what files are new since your last upload, and upload them:

```
$flagFile = Get-Item C:\csvFiles\lastupload.flg

Get-ChildItem -path C:\csvFiles\ -Filter *.csv | ? {$_.LastWriteTime -gt $flagFile.lastWriteTime} | ForEach {Upload-File $_.FullName}

New-Item -ItemType File -Force -Path $flagFile.FullName
```

Good luck!

Comment: Worked like a real treat.. thank you very much...Much appreciated